# . separated json value parsing with jq

Tags: linux, scripting, jq

I have this json and I'd like to go under the "rgw.main" but for some reason I'm not sure how to define.

```
{
    "bucket": "mybucket",
    "num_shards": 11,
    "tenant": "",
    "zonegroup": "xxx-11111",
    "placement_rule": "default-placement",
    "explicit_placement": {
        "data_pool": "",
        "data_extra_pool": "",
        "index_pool": ""
    },
    "id": "234324324",
    "marker": "234324324.2",
    "index_type": "Normal",
    "owner": "store",
    "ver": "0#1196975824,1#1195439377,2#1195232380,3#1194062417,4#1195521322,5#1195488056,6#1193225866,7#1195484409,8#1195542434,9#1195529602,10#1195327401",
    "master_ver": "0#0,1#0,2#0,3#0,4#0,5#0,6#0,7#0,8#0,9#0,10#0",
    "mtime": "2022-02-18T11:16:22.620065Z",
    "creation_time": "2021-03-12T10:02:54.033355Z",
    "max_marker": "0#01196975823.2645569872.5,1#01195439376.3395178223.5,2#01195232379.3168551901.5,3#01194062416.2633030768.5,4#01195521321.2647348717.5,5#01195488055.3126383883.5,6#01193225865.2630243615.5,7#01195484408.2645677558.5,8#01195542433.2655116258.5,9#01195529601.2621773307.5,10#01195327400.2629607598.5",
    "usage": {
        "rgw.none": {
            "size": 0,
            "size_actual": 0,
            "size_utilized": 0,
            "size_kb": 0,
            "size_kb_actual": 0,
            "size_kb_utilized": 0,
            "num_objects": 230
        },
        "rgw.main": {
            "size": 120124562767,
            "size_actual": 120220463104,
            "size_utilized": 120124562767,
            "size_kb": 117309144,
            "size_kb_actual": 117402796,
            "size_kb_utilized": 117309144,
            "num_objects": 29670
        },
        "rgw.multimeta": {
            "size": 0,
            "size_actual": 0,
            "size_utilized": 7776,
            "size_kb": 0,
            "size_kb_actual": 0,
            "size_kb_utilized": 8,
            "num_objects": 288
        }
    },
    "bucket_quota": {
        "enabled": false,
        "check_on_raw": false,
        "max_size": -1,
        "max_size_kb": 0,
        "max_objects": -1
    }
}
```

I'm trying to take out the rgw.main num_objects, however I can't get into only the rgw.main.

Tried like this but this gives back 3 number values:

```
.usage[].num_objects
```

Tried like this but this gives null:

```
.usage[].rgw.main.num_objects
```

Tried like this but this still null:

```
.usage[].rgw
```

What I'm missing?

Comment: Don't use the shortcut (i.e. omitting the quotes) if special characters are part of the identifier: `.usage."rgw.main".num_objects`

Comment: @pmf you're right and I've just tested on jqkungfu and it works properly, however on my linux machine still null. JQ version maybe or in linux need something more?

Comment: Ohh just found it, I missed the single quote: jq '.usage."rgw.main".num_objects'. Thank you for your help @pmf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple issues:

- `usage` is not an array but an object, so you need to navigate with `.usage`, not with `.usage[]`. `.usage[]` would iterate all values of the object, losing the keys.
- Your key is `"rgw.main"`, not `"rgw"."main"`. In other words, your object structure is `{ "rgw.main": 42 }` and not `{ "rgw": { "main": 42 } }`. You must use `."rgw.main"` or `.["rgw.main"]` if your key contains characters which are special to jq

```
.usage."rgw.main".num_objects
```

or

```
.usage["rgw.main"].num_objects
```

Output:

```
29670
```